# Using symmetry to evaluate integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I have this integral:

$$\int\int_D(x^3y^2+\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3))dA$$

Where $D: x^2+y^2 \le 1$

I was wondering what the best way to solve this using symmetry rather than using calculations? Any hints or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $g_1(x,y):=f(x,y)=x^3y^2+\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3)$
- $g_2(x,y):=f(-x,-y)=-x^3y^2-\ln(x^2-x+1)\sin(y^3)$
- $g_3(x,y):=f(-x,y)=-x^3y^2+\ln(x^2-x+1)\sin(y^3)$
- $g_4(x,y):=f(x,-y)=x^3y^2-\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3)$

then divide $D$ in $4$ sectors to obtain

$$\int\int_Df(x,y)dA=\\=\int\int_{D_1} g_1(x,y)dA+
\int\int_{D_2} g_2(x,y)dA+\int\int_{D_3} g_3(x,y)dA+\int\int_{D_4} g_4(x,y)dA$$

Comment: I see that we can use the union of all of these, but does this make it any easier because the double integral of each one is quite long

Comment: @JamesO'dare Note that the sum $g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4=0$.

Comment: Got it thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The function  $$f(x,y) =(x^3y^2) +(\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3)) $$ The first part namely $f_1(x,y)=(x^3y^2)$ satisfies  $$f_1(x,y)=-f_1(-x,y)$$

The second part namely $$f_2(x,y) =  (\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3))$$ satisfies $$f_2(x,y)=-f_1(x,-y)$$

Since the region is symmetric with respect to both $x-axis$ and $y-axis$  the positive and negative contributions cancel each other and you get $$\int\int_D(x^3y^2+\ln(x^2+x+1)\sin(y^3))dA=0$$

Comment: Your first statement is not correct, right? $f(x,-y)\neq f(x,y)$ in general (note the first term doesn't change sign with $y$ but the second term does, since $y^2$ is even but $\sin y^3$ is odd). Is that really what you meant?

Comment: @MPW Thanks for the comment. Please check the new version of my solution.